# Realm - sorting by a value from RealmDictionary

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-list

So realm now has maps, called RealmDictionary. Great. But can I sort RealmResults by a value that is inside an entry with a specific key?

Comment: What SDK are you using? I'm assuming Java/Kotlin since you're talking about maps, but will be useful to clarify.

Comment: Kotlin JVM [5 more to go]